Is there a way around hiding the block that contains my form 7 inside for those who already submitted it?
I have blocks for users to click and fill a form (form 7) inside. I want to hide the block itself from the homepage for users who submitted forms as they don't need to see it again since they have already submitted it. I keep finding solutions to hide the form itself, but my question is how to hide the block that holds this form altogether from my homepage for users who submitted it. Hope to find any help!
I tried the elementor form 7 display conditions which is nowhere close to what i need as it only hides the form itself (not the block altogther) according to users role or actions.
